# Metro 2.0 SOAP, specify date format in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, date, soap

I'm building a SOAP service that received a `java.util.Date` as a Web Param.
The problem is that I receive a date, in the request, as

> 2013-09-03T9:50:33.000+01:00

I get a null in the parameter. However, if the request sends the date as (notice the 0 before the hour 9):

> 2013-09-03T09:50:33.000+01:00

I get it properly.

Is there a way where I can defined the date format to be used so I match what the client sends? I'm looking for an answer that doesn't force me to change the parameter data type - that would be awesome.

Comment: It seems you are reading an XML parameter directly from the SOAP response. Instead use a WSDL generated SOAP Client for the web service. It auto generates a `Date` instance from the serialized data.

Comment: Thanks @Ravinder, I'm actually using SOAP UI to test it. My fear is that across platforms (.net for instance) it may no create the Date with the right format

Comment: Did you remove any doubt about this question? is SOAP using always the same format to transform a date to a string in the XML? And is it sure the web service will read correctly the date formatted in the sent XML? I'm really interested in the answer, as I have the same problem.